# How to get balances with wallet address and list token addresses?

Tags: javascript, testing, blockchain, solidity, truffle

Hi I'm new to blockchain, truffle and Solidity and I've been stuck on this problem for quite long. I want to get all token balances given a wallet address and the token contract addresses using a contract, but I keep encountering

**Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert**

whenever I test my contract.

Here's the code of my contract in Solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import {IERC20} from './IERC20.sol';

contract UtilityContract {
    function getBalances(address walletAddress, address[] memory tokenAddresses) public view returns (address[] memory, uint[] memory) {
        uint len = tokenAddresses.length;
        uint[] memory balances = new uint256[](len);
        for (uint i=0; i<len; i++) {
            balances[i] = IERC20(tokenAddresses[i]).balanceOf(walletAddress);
        }
        return (tokenAddresses, balances);
    }
}
```

and here's my test code:

```
const ADDRESS = "0xF977814e90dA44bFA03b6295A0616a897441aceC"; // some wallet address with token balance
const TOKENS = [    // token contract addresses
    "0x111111111117dC0aa78b770fA6A738034120C302",
    "0xC943c5320B9c18C153d1e2d12cC3074bebfb31A2",
];

const UtilityContract = artifacts.require('UtilityContract.sol');
contract('UtilityContract', ()=> {
    it('getBalances', async ()=> {
        const utilityContract = await UtilityContract.new();
        const output = await utilityContract.getBalances(ADDRESS, TOKENS);
        console.log(output);
    });
});
```

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image: revert error]

I imported the IERC20 interface to use the balanceOf function but for some reason it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this line into your code..
address() convert your wallet string to a valid wallet address format.

`IERC20(tokenAddresses[i]).balanceOf(address(walletAddress));`

Comment: Tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you tested on mainnet.
If so, the reason is that `0xC943c5320B9c18C153d1e2d12cC3074bebfb31A2` is not a token/contract.
To avoid this case, you need to use try/catch.

```
...
for (uint i=0; i<len; i++) {
    try IERC20(tokenAddresses[i]).balanceOf(walletAddress) returns (uint256 balance) {
        balances[i] = balance;
    } catch {}
}
...
```

P.S: Those two addresses in your `TOKENS` array are tokens/contracts on only BSC chain